# Laravel Session Flash Returns Null After Using Artisan Cache Commands Inside Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am trying to use a Session flash to return the success of clearing my websites cache. However, using the Artisan cache commands it seems that the session doesn't go through when returned back.

My controller function:

```
public function clearCache()
{
    $flushCache = Cache::flush();
    $clearCache = Artisan::call('cache:clear', ['--quiet' => true]);
    $routeCache = Artisan::call('route:cache', ['--quiet' => true]);
    $configCache = Artisan::call('config:cache', ['--quiet' => true]);
    $viewCache = Artisan::call('view:cache', ['--quiet' => true]);
    \Session::flash('alert', 'Site cache has been cleared');
    return back();
}
```

I have tried both of these methods

```
\Session::flash('alert', 'Site cache has been cleared');
return back();

return back()->with('alert', 'Site cache has been cleared');
```

But after dd()'ing the results, it returns null.

However, if I remove these commands

```
$flushCache = Cache::flush();
$clearCache = Artisan::call('cache:clear', ['--quiet' => true]);
$routeCache = Artisan::call('route:cache', ['--quiet' => true]);
$configCache = Artisan::call('config:cache', ['--quiet' => true]);
$viewCache = Artisan::call('view:cache', ['--quiet' => true]);
```

Then it works perfectly fine. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What session driver are you using?

Comment: @DarrylE.Clarke I came up with a solution. I just returned another function within the controller that handled the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old but I have had the same problem and it could be useful for someone.

Using Artisan to call `config:cache`, for some strange reason (to me), breaks the session and therefore the alert/success flash message does not appear.

I solved it by assigning the redirect to a variable before calling Artisan to return it afterwards, eg:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    // do staff

    $return = redirect()->route('...')->with('success', 'Update successfully!');

    Artisan::call('config:cache');

    return $return;
}
```